# Run once only in for loop to get name

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to express this code shorter?
I want to grab a repeated value once inside a loop.
It seems to me that there is a more sophisticated way then my approach.

Thy

**"row"** is a variable from a csv file.

**"station_h"** is the index of the weather station

**"station"** is the name of the weather station for the output.

```
for row in reader:
            self._get_station_name(row)
            .
            .


def _get_station_name(self, row):
    """Gets name of station once."""
    if self.station_flag:
        self.station = row[self.station_h]
        self.station_flag = False
```

Comment: use `break` maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas DataFrame.

Assuming that you have a DataFrame like this:

```
  station  some_values
0       A           12
1       B           14
2       C           19
3       A           15
4       E           18
5       A           22
```

Do: `df.station.drop_duplicates()`

And you'll get:

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
4    E
```

From here you can create your objects without needing to loop every time.

EDIT: You can use `pd.read_csv('path/to/csv')` to create your pandas DataFrame from your csv file. Note that you can use `delimtiter=';'` to specify your csv delimiter.